# How do I make a delay when using a .mcfunction file?

Tags: function, minecraft, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a map like the new Among Us game pooping about but I'm running into a problem: I cant make a delay between commands.

I tried on my own, but changed to looking up tutorials but their only for Minecraft Java Edition.
I tried many things like using the scoreboard command but it uses repeating commands which you cant do in a mcfunction file.
I have also tried making a command that sets a delay but I cant use it in a .mcfunction file due to it being a 'custom' command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`schedule`](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/schedule).

To create one:

```
schedule function <function> <time> [append|replace]
```

To clear one:

```
schedule clear <function>
```

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to make it count down from five using a title command like in the original game. I'll go test your answer now.

Comment: I am not the best command blocker, so please can you explain what's happening?

So I know what to put in the parameters.

Comment: `schedule function [functionName] [ticks]t`. For example: `schedule function FunctionName 50t`